# Best Practice Database Types for Joomla Programming

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm curious what others have found to be the best choices when building databases for your backend components (or modules) in Joomla.

For example, in a simple backend carousel in a database I would use:

---

**id** as **smallint unsigned**, not expecting the number of items to ever reach 65k

**img** I do **varchar** and put the url pointing to the file to be uploaded

**title** I do **tinytext** since I don't expect it to ever be over 255 characters for the title.

**description** I've been using **text** because I don't expect them to reach 65k on this... also, this text description would be displayed below the picture in a lightbox if the carousel item is clicked on.

**link**  this would go in a different type of carousel, but for example, if I had a link I would use **varchar** just like the img url.

**ordering**  here I use **smallint unsigned** just like with id because it could potentially reach that (not as easily as ID, which is autoincrement and so keeps increasing even after items are deleted...).

**published** for this I use **tinyint**  ...is that the best option?  there's no boolean that I'm aware of.

---

I'm currently using MySQLi and developing on Joomla 2.5.9 (but eventually/soon to move to 3.x).

Answer (score 1):

I tend to follow what's used in the Joomla! core, so that my tables, models, controllers etc can make best use of the JTable, JModel etc features, so:

```
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`description` mediumtext NOT NULL,
`state` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`images` text NOT NULL,
`urls` text NOT NULL,
`ordering` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

Note, that `published` became `state` as there are more than just the Published and Unpublished states in use (e.g. `Trashed`, `Archived` and custom options as well).

Comment: Interesting, urls, images as text seems wasteful, but I'm curious why the Joomla developers chose to go that route with those.  Also, published became state in 3.0?  Thanks for your response.

Comment: Published is State after 1.6.

Comment: Actually, State === State for most of components. For Contacts component, State is stored is Published column, because of collisions with address field (state as Alaska). I recommend using Published in your component I think it hasn't been changed all over for backward compatibility

Comment: I'm curious, what is the maximum number of rows of data I can store with an id of int(10)?